# How to reshape a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, formatting, reshape

I have a list of tuples that looks like this: `B=[('dict1', 'dict2'), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]`. Of course `dict1` and `dict2` refer to two dictionaries which values are shown in the table-like view below.

I want to reshape it so that a table-like view is produced, with the purpose of later writing it to a `csv` file:

```
dict1   dict2
1       5
2       6
3       7
4       8
```

I have tried with `data=B.reshape(2,5)` but to no avail since this is not the way to reshape a list.

**How could this be done in a pythonic way?** Thanks!

Comment: You should use the Pandas library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write in a csv file try:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(B)
```

Result:

```
dict1   dict2
1       5
2       6
3       7
4       8
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
In [22]: import pandas as pd

In [23]: B=[('dict1', 'dict2'), (1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7),]

In [24]: pd.DataFrame(B).to_csv("my_file.csv", header=False, index=False, sep="\t")
```

Result:

```
$ cat my_file.csv
  dict1 dict2
  1     5
  2     6
  3     7
```